# Удалить type='text/javascript' из вызова скриптов Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Необходимо удалить type='text/javascript' из вызова скриптов Wordpress.

Функция

```
wp_register_script( 'tab-shortcode' , plugins_url('tab'.$suffix.'.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-tabs'), '1.0', true );
```

Сейчас

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.terratel.eu/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>↩
```

Необходимо

```
<script src='/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>↩
```

Comment: Хм. А в чем смысл?

Comment: Валидность https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.terratel.eu%2Fsip-e1-gateway.html#l468c118

Comment: А это валидно. Избыточно, но совершенно валидно.

Comment: Ну так найди функцию `wp_register_script` и измени его

Comment: Функция https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/ , что изменять?

Comment: Вам нужен хук script_loader_tag https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/. Но, вообще-то, вы занимаетесь 100% ерундой.

Comment: Это в function темы вставлять? Вставил - не работает.

Comment: @tomas_morgam чтобы использовать хук, надо понимать, что вы делаете. Копипаста не поможет.

Comment: Ну вот, ещё один поциент, считающий предупреждения ошибками. Это не нужно исправлять.

Comment: Думаю, стоит попробовать как-нибудь так:
`add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'clean_style_tag');
function clean_style_tag($src) {
    return str_replace("type='text/css'", '', $src);
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');
function clean_script_tag($src) {
    return str_replace("type='text/javascript'", '', $src);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в конец **functions.php**

```
// удалить атрибут type у scripts и styles
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'clean_style_tag');
function clean_style_tag($src) {
    return str_replace("type='text/css'", '', $src);
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');
function clean_script_tag($src) {
    return str_replace("type='text/javascript'", '', $src);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');
    function clean_script_tag($src) {
    return str_replace(" type='text/javascript'", '', $src);
}
```