# Wordpress тэги вида `<script type="8ed8dc17de967833ca9721df-text/javascript">`

Tags: wordpress

Не могу никак докопать, откуда они возникают.
Wordpress 5.0.3. 
Пробовал отключать все плагины.
Перебрал разные способы, которыми убирают type='text/javascript'.
И это [Удалить type='text/javascript' из вызова скриптов Wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764811/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-type-text-javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-wordpress)
, и это
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287830/remove-type-attribute-from-script-and-style-tags-added-by-wordpress

Скрипты подключал и как положено, и напрямую в header вставлял, и с помощью add_action на 'wp_head', с разными приоритетами.

Результат один - на выходе тэги вида `<script type="8ed8dc17de967833ca9721df-text/javascript">`, комбинация символов меняется.

Зачем собственно это нужно. 
Надо добавить некий скрипт от GoogleAnalytics. И вроде бы работает, но из-за этих лишних символов не проходит проверку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где стоит поискать?

P.S. Пробовал вариант с такой регуляркой:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'output_buffer_start');
function output_buffer_start() { 
    ob_start("output_callback"); 
}
add_action('shutdown', 'output_buffer_end');
function output_buffer_end() { 
    ob_end_flush(); 
}
function output_callback($buffer) {
    return preg_replace( "%[ ]type=[\'\"](.*?)-text\/(javascript|css)[\'\"]%", '', $buffer );
}
```

Comment: Таких тегов WP не создаёт. Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную, переустановите ядро.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, wp действительно оказался не при чем.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, в результате выяснилось, что <strike>шоколад</strike> wp не виноват, плагины тоже, такие штуки проделывает cloudflare, за которым сидит сайт.